# How to execute custom actions sequentially in WIX

Tags: wix

I have 2 custom actions in WIX A and B

I need B to execute only after A is finished.

A is an external exe, B is a set of commands which configures A, and therefore cannot execute before A.

Currently I define 2 custom actions like this:

```
<CustomAction Id='install_exe_action' FileKey='exe'  Execute='deferred' Return='check'  ExeCommand=' --flags 1'/> 

<CustomAction Id='start_service_controller_action' FileKey='exe_service_controller_exe' Impersonate='no' ExeCommand=' /install ' Execute='deferred' Return='check' />
```

I then have 2 InstallExecuteSequence sections like:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='install_exe_action' After='InstallFiles'> NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE </Custom> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>  


<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='start_service_controller_action' After='InstallFiles'> NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE </Custom> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

How can I get start_service_controler_action to only happen AFTER install_exe_action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='install_exe_action' After='InstallFiles'> NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE </Custom> 
  <Custom Action='start_service_controller_action' After='install_exe_action'> NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE </Custom> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: THANKS! Thats perfect